# Ecommerce Tracking Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, e-commerce

I have got the code required to track 1 item in my Ecommerce website.

Code:

```
// Called when a product is added to a shopping cart.
function addToCart(product) {
  ga('ec:addProduct', {
    'id': product.id,
    'name': product.name,
    'category': product.category,
    'brand': product.brand,
    'variant': product.variant,
    'price': product.price,
    'quantity': product.qty
  });
  ga('ec:setAction', 'add');
  ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'add to cart');     // Send data using an event.
}
```

I just have to add the names of my strings into the id, name, category, etc.

I am looking to add multiple elements into this one code, do i need a loop or can i do something like this:

```
// Called when a product is added to a shopping cart.
    function addToCart(product) {
      ga('ec:addProduct', {
        'id1': product.id1,
        'id2': product.id2,
        'id3': product.id3,
        'id4': product.id4,
    ADD ALL OTHER ELEMENTS
 });
      ga('ec:setAction', 'add');
      ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'add to cart');     // Send data using an event.
    }
```

Any assistance would be great. Please keep in mind I am new to writing code and wonder if this will function without error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have separate "addProduct" block for each product in the cart